# StanfordCoreNLP - Setting pipelineLanguage to German not working?

Tags: stanford-nlp, pycorenlp

I am using the `pycorenlp` client in order to talk to the Stanford CoreNLP Server. In my setup I am setting `pipelineLanguage` to `german` like this:

```py
from pycorenlp import StanfordCoreNLP

nlp = StanfordCoreNLP('http://localhost:9000')

text = 'Das große Auto.'

output = nlp.annotate(text, properties={
  'annotators': 'tokenize,ssplit,pos,depparse,parse',
  'outputFormat': 'json',
  'pipelineLanguage': 'german'
  })
```

However, from the looks I'd say that it's not working:

```py
output['sentences'][0]['tokens']
```

will return:

```
[{'after': ' ',
  'before': '',
  'characterOffsetBegin': 0,
  'characterOffsetEnd': 3,
  'index': 1,
  'originalText': 'Das',
  'pos': 'NN',
  'word': 'Das'},
 {'after': ' ',
  'before': ' ',
  'characterOffsetBegin': 4,
  'characterOffsetEnd': 9,
  'index': 2,
  'originalText': 'große',
  'pos': 'NN',
  'word': 'große'},
 {'after': '',
  'before': ' ',
  'characterOffsetBegin': 10,
  'characterOffsetEnd': 14,
  'index': 3,
  'originalText': 'Auto',
  'pos': 'NN',
  'word': 'Auto'},
 {'after': '',
  'before': '',
  'characterOffsetBegin': 14,
  'characterOffsetEnd': 15,
  'index': 4,
  'originalText': '.',
  'pos': '.',
  'word': '.'}]
```

This should be more like

```
     Das  große  Auto
POS:  DT     JJ    NN
```

It seems to me that setting `'pipelineLanguage': 'de'` does not work for some reason.

I've executed

```
java -mx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -port 9000 -timeout 15000
```

in order to start the server.

---

I am getting the following from the logger:

```
[main] INFO CoreNLP - StanfordCoreNLPServer listening at /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000
[pool-1-thread-3] ERROR CoreNLP - Failure to load language specific properties: StanfordCoreNLP-german.properties for german
[pool-1-thread-3] INFO CoreNLP - [/127.0.0.1:60700] API call w/annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,depparse,parse
Das große Auto.
[pool-1-thread-3] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator tokenize
[pool-1-thread-3] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.TokenizerAnnotator - No tokenizer type provided. Defaulting to PTBTokenizer.
[pool-1-thread-3] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator ssplit
[pool-1-thread-3] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator pos
[pool-1-thread-3] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger - Loading POS tagger from edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger ... done [0.5 sec].
[pool-1-thread-3] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator depparse
[pool-1-thread-3] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.parser.nndep.DependencyParser - Loading depparse model file: edu/stanford/nlp/models/parser/nndep/english_UD.gz ... 
[pool-1-thread-3] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.parser.nndep.Classifier - PreComputed 99996, Elapsed Time: 8.645 (s)
[pool-1-thread-3] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.parser.nndep.DependencyParser - Initializing dependency parser ... done [9.8 sec].
[pool-1-thread-3] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator parse
[pool-1-thread-3] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.parser.common.ParserGrammar - Loading parser from serialized file edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz ... done [0.3 sec].
```

Apparently the server is loading the models for the English language - without warning me about that.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I just downloaded the models jar for [German](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-german-corenlp-2017-06-09-models.jar) from the [website](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/) and moved it into the directory where I extracted the server e.g.

```
~/Downloads/stanford-corenlp-full-2017-06-09 $
```

After re-running the server, the model was successfully loaded.

```
[pool-1-thread-3] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator tokenize
[pool-1-thread-3] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator ssplit
[pool-1-thread-3] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator pos
[pool-1-thread-3] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger - Loading POS tagger from edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/german/german-hgc.tagger ... done [5.1 sec].
[pool-1-thread-3] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator depparse
[pool-1-thread-3] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.parser.nndep.DependencyParser - Loading depparse model file: edu/stanford/nlp/models/parser/nndep/UD_German.gz ... 
[pool-1-thread-3] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.parser.nndep.Classifier - PreComputed 99984, Elapsed Time: 11.419 (s)
[pool-1-thread-3] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.parser.nndep.DependencyParser - Initializing dependency parser ... done [12.2 sec].
[pool-1-thread-3] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator parse
[pool-1-thread-3] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.parser.common.ParserGrammar - Loading parser from serialized file edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/germanFactored.ser.gz ... done [1.0 sec].
[pool-1-thread-3] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator lemma
[pool-1-thread-3] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator ner
[pool-1-thread-3] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier - Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/german.conll.hgc_175m_600.crf.ser.gz ... done [0.7 sec].
```